# Elixir: comparison with nil is forbidden as it is unsafe

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am very new to `Elixir`. I am facing this error:

```
2022-07-06 13:52:53.022 [info] pid=<0.31.0> Application mt_consumer exited: MTConsumer.Application.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: MTConsumer
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (ArgumentError) comparison with nil is forbidden as it is unsafe. If you want to check if a value is nil, use is_nil/1 instead
            (ecto) lib/ecto/query/builder.ex:551: Ecto.Query.Builder.not_nil!/1
            (mt_model) lib/mt_model/location.ex:36: MTModel.Location.raw_id_by_name_tenant/2
            (mt_consumer) lib/mt_consumer.ex:66: MTConsumer.handle_job/1
            (mt_consumer) lib/mt_consumer.ex:38: MTConsumer.loop/1
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:365: :supervisor.do_start_child/2
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:348: :supervisor.start_children/3
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:314: :supervisor.init_children/2
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:328: :gen_server.init_it/6
```

Now here is my code:

```
def id_by_name_tenant(name, tenant_id) do
    id = raw_id_by_name_tenant(name, tenant_id)

    case id do
      nil -> raw_id_by_name_tenant(@default_name, nil)
      _ -> id
    end
  end

  defp raw_id_by_name_tenant(name, tenant_id) do
    from(
      l in MTModel.Location,
      where: l.name == ^name and l.tenant_id == ^tenant_id,
      limit: 1,
      select: l.id
    ) |> MTModel.Repo.one([])
  end

  defp raw_id_by_name_tenant(name, _) do
    from(
      l in MTModel.Location,
      where: l.name == ^name,
      limit: 1,
      select: l.id
    ) |> MTModel.Repo.one()
  end
```

what am I doing wrong here? The code worked fine earlier but upon re deploying it started creating problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second clause of `raw_id_by_name_tenant/2` will never match, since the first one will always do. You probably forgot to guard against `nil` in the first clause, for example

```elixir
defp raw_id_by_name_tenant(name, tenant_id) when tenant_id != nil do
```

or move the second clause up and replace it with

```elixir
defp raw_id_by_name_tenant(name, nil) do
```

But I think you might be able to simplify this code by using [`Repo.get_by/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:get_by/3), removing the need for a private function and making the intent clearer (if your name/tenant_id pairs are unique):

```elixir
def id_by_name_tenant(name, tenant_id) do
  query = select(MTModel.Location, [l], l.id)
  case Repo.get_by(query, name: name, tenant_id: tenant_id) do
    nil -> Repo.get_by(query, name: @default_name)
    id -> id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling function `raw_id_by_name_tenant/2` with a `nil` parameter, and then check it with a field here:

```elixir
where: l.name == ^name and l.tenant_id == ^tenant_id,
```

This is forbidden in Ecto, if you have to check for nil you have to use [`is_nil/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#is_nil/1).

Instead of passing nil to your query you can refactor you function with [`dynamic/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#dynamic/2):

```elixir
  defp raw_id_by_name_tenant(name, tenant_id) do
    from(
      l in MTModel.Location,
      where: ^with_name(name) and ^with_tenant_id(tenant_id),
      limit: 1,
      select: l.id
    ) |> MTModel.Repo.one([])
  end

  defp with_name(nil), do: true
  defp with_name(name), do: dynamic([l], l.name == ^name)

  defp with_tenant_id(nil), do: true
  defp with_tenant_id(tenant_id), do: dynamic([l], l.tenant_id == ^tenant_id)
```